# How do I reload a partial view using the Jquery .load()?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view on my page that I would like to reload. It is located in the "Attachments" div.

What I'm doing at the moment which is not working is by using the following command:

```
$('#attachments').load('@Url.Action("Attachments" "Transactions",new {id=1297})')
```

The above will give me an error in the console of:

```
GET http://localhost:49793/Transactions/@Url.Action(%22Attachments%22 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I missing? Why is the URL.Action() not rendered properly?

The action Attachments in the Transaction controller is [ChildActionOnly].

Comment: Because you have the script in a separate file (razor code is not parsed in external js files. Put in in the view, or declare a variable in the view for the url, and pass that to the function.

Comment: Do you understand what @StephenMuecke suggested ? That is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your action url comes from your backend. In the way that you are doing it, you're sending just a string with your backend action, not the url.

One possible way it's to use a data-attribute in your html like:

```
<div id="attachments" data-url="@Url.Action("Attachments" "Transactions",new {id=1297})"></div>
```

and in your javascript:

```
var $attachments = $('#attachments'),
    url = $attachments.data('url'); 

$attachments.load(url)
```

or even a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="attachmentsUrl" value="@Url.Action("Attachments" "Transactions",new {id=1297})" />

var url = $('#attachmentsUrl').val(); 

$('#attachments').load(url)
```

or you can try some other variations, just be attended to render your url in your markup